# Dart cannot read readAsStringSync

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-test, flutter-dependencies, dart-2

I am using
`Dart VM version: 1.24.3 (Wed Dec 13 23:26:59 2017) on "macos_x64"`
WITH
`Flutter 0.2.8 • channel beta
Framework • revision b397406561 (13 days ago)
Engine • revision c903c217a1
Tools • Dart 2.0.0-dev.43.0.flutter-52afcba357`

`ReadAsStringSync` is giving me an empty string as an output rather than the required file content, my code is

```
var appl = new File('a.txt').readAsStringSync();
print(appl);
```

also i need help with the readAsString method as it returns a `Future<String>`, i want to know that is there any method or way to convert it into `String`

Comment: The Dart VM version is irrelevant when you are working with Flutter. Only the versions provided by `flutter doctor` or `flutter version` are relevant.

Answer (score 2):

```
Future<String> readFile(String path) {
  return new File(path).readAsString();
}

void foo() async {
  var result = await readFile(path);
  print(result);
}
```

or

```
String readFile(String path) async {
  var result = await new File(path).readAsString();
  print(result);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to print the value of the returned string someplace else and it gives me **Instance of 'Future' ** as output rather than the string

Comment: With "somplace else" you probable mean where there is no `async` in the method signature and without `await`. That won't work.  If you can provide concrete code I might be able to make concrete suggestions.

Comment: `var a; // defined globally ie outside any class and method`. and then i call `void foo() async{
a = await readFile('/Users/rajatyadav97/desktop/flutter/assignment_teams/lib/a.txt');}` and print it in `main()` it gives me null as output ps. sorry i am new to dart and stack

Comment: The `print(...)` in `main()` is probably executed before `a = await readFile ...` was able to assign the value. I think you should read about async https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures, https://www.dartlang.org/articles/language/await-async